# Json file in excel

Tags: json, excel

I would like to open a json file on Excel to sepparate the fields in rows. I see that on internet there are many converters, but i can´t upload the information i´m working with to internet. is there any manual way or a method to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can download/copy this code locally from jsfiddle.net:
http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM

It uses the **JSONToCSVConvertor** object of JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var data = $('#txt').val();
        if(data == '')
            return;

        JSONToCSVConvertor(data, "Vehicle Report", true);
   });
});
```

The full code from jsfiddle.net includes only HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so you can simply run it locally.
Afterwords, you can paste your JSON code and generate the CSV/Excel file.